# Setting a Button visibility to GONE when I click on a ListView

Tags: android

I want to make related button's visibility gone when I click on listview but it only works for first button on the listview.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
          btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);// this works for first button
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try this way Like : Button btn = parent.findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: is the button in the listview item , if so it would be easier if you do this in the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of button is wrong in this case. Edit it like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

      Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
      btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);// this works for first button
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the visibility of the button you've selected in

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
```

not of the clicked item.

You need to do

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id {
      view.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Setting the visibility of the selected view
    }
});
```

Comment: my listview contains checkbox textview and button in every single row. I just want button to disappear, Your code works for all items.

Answer (score 0):

**Soultion:**

You need to first get the position of which item you're clicking, try this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id {

      (your_list_view).getchildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh).setVisibility(View.Gone) // Setting the visibility of the selected view

    }
});
```

Hope it helps.